# Infinite set with discrete metric

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be an infinite set. For $p\in X$ and $q\in X$, define $d(p,q)=1-\delta_{pq}$.

Prove that this is a metric. Which subsets of the resulting metric space are open? Which are closed? Which are compact?

My proof: I proved that this is really a metric. Also any subsets of $X$ are open and closed. What about compact subsets of $\text{discr}(X)$?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: For any $A\subseteq X$, the family $\big\{\{x\}:x\in A\big\}$ is an open cover of $A$; when does it have a finite subcover?

Comment: if $A$ is a finite set.

Comment: @Pacman: You’ve got it: that’s exactly right.

Comment: I knew this because any finite set in any metric space $(X, \rho)$ are compact. But if $A$ is infinite set then $\{\{x\}: x\in A\}$ will be an open cover of $A$ which contains no finite subcover of $A$ because $A$ is infinite. Am I true?

Comment: @Pacman: Yes, that’s right, because if you omit any of the sets $\{x\}$ with $x\in A$, you no longer have a cover of $A$.

Comment: @Pacman: You’re very welcome.